# Matrix multiplication with its transpose

Tags: c++, opencv

I´m a beginner in opencv and have the following question:

How can I calculate the multiplication of the transpose of a Mat1d matrix with itself and store it in a Matx22d element?

```
Mat1d A(4, 2);
Matx22d AtA = Matx22d::zeros();
```

I tried the following:

```
AtWA = A.t * A;
```

but it gives me an error telling me that this is not allowed

Comment: `A.t` is a pointer to the function, you need to call the function via parantheses, ie. `A.t()`

Comment: Ok. I did that but know i get an error that there "couldn´t be an operator found, that accepts a right side operand of type cv::MatExpr". 
Has this maybe to do with the conversion from Mat1d to Mat22xd?

Comment: First, `Matx` variants are for compile time constant matrices. But, you are using runtime matrix type `Mat`. Second, any operation on `Mat` classes return a `MatExpr` instead of a `Mat`, therefore the operations run only on the assignment time. Here, on the right side the multiplication returns a `MatExpr` but `Matx` cannot be assigned from `MatExpr`. `AtA` should be a `Mat` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Matx12d A(4,2);
Matx22d AtA = A.t() * A;
```